# How does addObserver:forKeyPath: work on a static class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, key-value-observing, static-class

I'm trying to build a static class called Logger that will upload the log files at some point, when called like `[Logger uploadLogFiles]`.

I'm trying to add an observer to this static class like so:

`[Logger addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"uploadComplete" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`

I do this just before starting an asynchronous call method for NSURLConnection. I do get a warning, saying *Incompatible pointer types sending `Class` to parameter of type `NSObject *`*.

However, this does not seem to work, as the `observerValueForKeyPath:` method never gets called.

Has anybody had any experience with adding observers to static variables in static classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Class has no instance variables, so there is nothing to observe.

You need to have an actual object (an instance of a class) for KVO.

Comment: It's reassuring to find this answer here but do you have a source?

Comment: @Matt A source for what? A class itself doesn't have instance variables, You need an instance of a class to have instance variables. Have a look at the Objective-C reference.